# Three.js Stereo Effect not lining up

Tags: three.js

I'm using Stero Effect in Three.js for a simple VR player, and the views don't line up - i.e. the right view is pointing a little more to the left than the left view and vice versa.

I've looked through all the examples and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. No one else seems to have this problem

```
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1024);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    target = new THREE.Vector3();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.autoClear = false;


     effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);
     effect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

//in the renderer

```
    if(vrMode)
        effect.render(scene, camera);
    else
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Has anyone seen this before or know what else might cause it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the eye separation parameter. Try to set it to 0 it worked for me. 
The parameter is on the StereoEffect.js file: `this.separation`